# Field formatting

Tags: validation, format

I'm looking for a way to restrict how a field gets formatted.

I have a channel for a podcast that should always be in the format of hh:mm:ss - despite the instructions making this clear, editors tend to ignore and invariably we end up with 45.

Is there a way I can take that input and format appropriately or even alert on the frontend that what they've given doesn't validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a table field with a column for HH/MM/SS, with each one restricted to numbers?

[image]

Alternatively you could use https://github.com/fruitstudios/craft-validateit with a custom regex rule, but I've no idea what that would need to be.

Comment: Thanks man. Regex looks like a great option. This field already exists so would mean retrofitting a bunch of stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string 